# Closing all sections of a UITable

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a UItable that has expandable cells.
When the user taps on a section it expands and shows the rows. But I need to close any previously opened sections before the new section is opened. I guess I need to do this in didselectrow, just not sure how to do it??

My code for didselectrow is below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView.tag == 4)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Did Select Row");

        if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
        {
            if (!indexPath.row)
            {
                // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
                [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

                NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
                BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections3 containsIndex:section];
                NSInteger rows;


                NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

                if (currentlyExpanded)
                {
                    rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                    [expandedSections3 removeIndex:section];

                }
                else
                {
                    [expandedSections3 addIndex:section];
                    rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                }


                for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
                {
                    NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];
                     [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
                }

                //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                if (currentlyExpanded)
                {
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                }
                else
                {
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                }
            }

            else {

            }
        }

        //NSLog(@"Button Pressed?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking UITableView's `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` from within `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. This lets the table view re-query your delegate for the sections you specify. As a benefit you will get a nice animation for rows that are being added and removed in this way.

Of course, this is quite different from your current solution where you are directly manipulating the table view's row, so if you want to try `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` you may need to rewrite substantial parts of your delegate. The changes will involve storing the collapsed/expanded state of your sections, either directly in your delegate or in a model object referenced by the delegate, so that the delegate has the updated return values when it is re-queried by the table view.

Comment: hi, are there any tutorials you know of that might be able to help me with your recommendation??

Comment: @hanimal_p: No, I don't have any specific tutorial. I would recommend studying Apple's documentation for `UITableView`, notably the part about the various reload methods. Then there is Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html), and finally I would resort to [googling](https://www.google.ch/search?q=uitableview+tutorial+reloaddata). If you are confused about the "state saving" or the "model object" part, I recommend looking up the MVC design pattern.